# playing music from playlist - wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, objectlistview

I have created a simple music player using wxPython which has a Frame and a Panel and plays music using the tutorial given [here](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/04/20/wxpython-creating-a-simple-mp3-player/).

Furthermore I also added a playlist functionality to this which uses `ObjectListView` and shows all tracks from a `.m3u` file. 
This playList is a separate python module which

```
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):

def __init__(self, parent, playListSelected):
    //stuff

def GetOLVColClicked(self, event):
    item = event.GetEventObject().GetSelectedObjects()
    print item[0]['path']

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, playList):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, 
                      title="ObjectListView Demo", size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self, playList)

class GenApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, playList, redirect=False, filename=None):
        self.playList = playList
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MainFrame(self.playList)
        frame.Show()
        return True
```

On clicking on any track in the playlist I can get the entire path of the song.
I was wondering how to send this song to the existing music player and play it.
Or is this approach wrong and is there a better approach to accomodate the playlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is pretty close to the way I was thinking of doing it back when I was pondering how to enhance my own mp3 player. To pass information between classes, I think that pubsub is by far the most elegant solution, even if it is a little magical. You can read my [tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/) on the subject or you can read about it on the wxPython wiki:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Controlling%20GUI%20with%20pubsub
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/WxLibPubSub

Comment: This is a wonderful library and a great tutorial too. And it solved my issue. Thanks @Mike.